# Unsubscribing from ROS Topic - Python

Tags: python, ros, unsubscribe

So I have a Class and in its init function, I subscribe to a camera, whose callback function is created in my class. i.e:

```
class example(object):
  def __init__(self):
    rospy.subscriber("/cameras/left_hand_camera/image",Image,self.callback_viewer)
  def callback_viewer(self,data):
    try:
      cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "bgr8")
    except CvBridgeError as e:
      print(e)
    cv2.imshow("window", cv_image)
```

So for the purposes of my project, I need to create another class, which, in addition to doing some other stuff, unsubscribe to all the topics it is currently subscribing to. but I don't know how to use the unsubscriber function listed [here](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/rospy/html/rospy.topics.Subscriber-class.html)

Can anyone help me with that, how would i use that function?

Answer (score 9):

I don't understand exactly what you have to do, but when you subscribe to a topic, you can write something like this:

```
sub = rospy.subscriber("/cameras/left_hand_camera/image",Image,self.callback_viewer)
```

Then when you have to unsubscribe you just have to do:

```
sub.unregister()
```

Hope this answer your question.